# Mac and Windows alternative to KeePass?

Tags: windows, mac, passwords, keepass

Hey I want to sync passwords between a Mac and a PC with the database being stored on an FTP site. However, KeePassX can't open KeyPass 2.x databases, and neither KeePass 1.x or KeePassX seems to allow opening over FTP anyway. Does anyone currently use an alternative to KeePass that has Mac and Windows versions that allows the database to be stored on a remote server and accessed by SFTP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[KeePass pro](http://keepass.info/download.html) version is .net and supports mono so runs fine on Windows, Mac and Linux, and supports opening files over ftp.

Alternatively you can use KeePass1/KeePassX with a [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) account, that way you don't have to open the file over FTP, you just allow Dropbox to sync the local copy of the file every time you make a change. (Dropbox supports Windows, Mac and Linux)

Comment: Oh, I missed that little Mono there. That would work on my Mac which has Mono! That's the answer, thanks!

Comment: +1 for KeePass1 & KeePassX with Dropbox. That's what I use to sync between Windows and Mac.

Comment: FYI - it looks like the latest version of KeePassX doesn't require that you install mono first -> http://www.keepassx.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

There is [SecuStore2](http://maklesoft.com/secustore/), I don't think it is widely used and it doesn't encrypt all data like the KeePass family does. Things like password titles are not encrypted. But that's the same for other apps like Apple's Keychain and 1Password. [SecuStore2](http://maklesoft.com/secustore/) is a cheaper option than 1Password.

Comment: When Answering a Question where you give suggestions of Products please try to provide links.